# Can you have no or weak constraint on foreign key in MySQL or any database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm aware that most databases will have foreign key constraint set to either "SET NULL", "CASCADE", "NO ACTION", or "RESTRICT". The default is usually No Action meaning that the delete operation will be rolled back.

What if I want a "loose" or "weak" reference? That is, if the link exist, great! If it doesn't, who cares, let it break!

I came across this problem when trying to design my first database for a fitness app with custom exercises created by many users. These custom exercises can be used by any other users.

Let's say for example:

1. UserA creates ExerciseA.
2. UserB logs ExerciseA.
3. UserA deletes ExerciseA.
4. UserB retains ExerciseA's logs, but cannot reference ExerciseA itself because it is deleted.

This scenario is similar to a Youtube's playlist where the video can be taken down, which will be shown as a broken link - this is an expected behaviour. No referential integrity needed. The playlist's item itself exist and expects a parent video, but the video doesn't exist anymore.

"On delete set null" seems to be the best option here, but I need to keep ExerciseID in the Log table because it is used as part of a composite key(the exercise log is uniquely identified by UserID, ExerciseID and a timestamp). Don't use foreign key and constraint altogether? I don't know what is the best practice here. Help!

Comment: Do not use deletion, use `status` column with possible `'deleted'` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, the short answer is "No". You can't have a foreign key without enforcing its referential integrity. It defeats the whole purpose of having a foreign key in the first place which governs the rule that a piece of information has to exist in the database.

Well, I don't want referential integrity, so I don't need a foreign key! I'll go so far as to say that not every relationship needs referential integrity. A good read to put my mind at ease on this concept: https://ardalis.com/related-data-without-foreign-keys/